# MySQL ORDER BY with multiple INNER JOINs

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to figure out how to order by in this MySQL select. I hope you can help me out.

**Tabels:**

categories

```
catId, catParentId, catDisplay
1      0            1
2      0            1
3      0            1
4      1            1
5      1            1
```

categories_translation

```
transId, catId, catName, catDesc, langId
1        1      Title1   Desc1    1
2        2      Title2   Desc2    1
3        3      Title3   Desc3    1
4        4      Title4   Desc4    1
5        5      Title5   Desc5    1
```

language

```
langId, langName, langCode
1       Danish    da
2       English   en
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT `categories`.`catId`,
       `categories`.`catParentId`,
       `categories`.`catDisplay`,
       `categories_translation`.`catName`,
       `categories_translation`.`catDesc`,
       `language`.`langCode`
FROM   `categories`
INNER JOIN `categories_translation` ON `categories_translation`.`catId` = `categories`.`catId`
INNER JOIN `language` ON `language`.`langId` = `categories_translation`.`langId`
WHERE `language`.`langCode` = 'da'
```

Now, I get returned what I want, but is there a way to order the child categories to their parents, so the result looks like this:

**Desired result:**

```
catId | catParentId | catDisplay | catName | catDesc | langCode
1       0             1            Title1    Desc1     da
4       1             1            Title4    Desc4     da
5       1             1            Title5    Desc5     da
2       0             1            Title2    Desc2     da
3       0             1            Title3    Desc3     da
```

I've tried order by, but can seem to get the results like I want.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do.. "order the child categories to their parents" - please explain a little more. Sorry if its just me. What makes the CatId 4 and 5 come after 1, but before 2?

Comment: `[1,0],[4,1],[5,1],[2,0],[3,0]...` What sort order is that?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the current output looks like?

Comment: i don't see any pattern at all in the desired result

Comment: @Kim I had to use my pattern recognition super powers on your intended result, to figure out the answer.  It would have been easier for others to identify if you mentioned _hierarchical_ ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN categories.catParentId = 0 THEN
        categories.catId
    ELSE 
        categories.catParentId
    END,
    CASE WHEN categories.catParentId = 0 THEN
        0
    ELSE
        categories.catId
    END
```

For those that don't get the ordering it would be easier to think of the desired result as:

```
catId | catParentId | orderingCategory
1       0             1.0
4       1             1.4
5       1             1.5
2       0             2.0
3       0             3.0
```

So it's a hierarchy of categories, OP wants to order the result so that each parent categories are followed by their child categories.

Comment: Congratulations on deciphering the intention - that might just be it.

Comment: I don't see what causes 4 and 5 to go after 1, but before 2 and 3 >< This is bugging me. Maybe I'll post a Q lol

Answer (score 2):

You can't get the results you like, because its not possible. I can't see a pattern or an id which allow to order the way you want.

Why title 4, title 5 go first?

I can't see the logic. Maybe the example is incomplete, maybe the order of CatName and CatDesc is the key you need.

Comment: It may actually be possible - but it's not deterministic without more information.  In theory, you can use a case statement or other mechanism to ensure any order you can imagine, as long as you have concrete rules.

Comment: i think so that this case is more an information omission than a it's a impossible thing

Comment: In the categories tabel, the ones with a id in "catParentId" are ment to be subcategories to category "1", hence the logic for ordering the result like i described, but i guess it's not posible?

Comment: Absolutely, is possible, but in this case, with this conditions, i believe it's not

Comment: @Rafael, the categories_translation adds a name to the categories tabel, since i have muliple translations for a single category, and want an option to add more without altering in the database

Answer (score -3):

```
ORDER BY catParentID, catID, ...
```